# iOS Developer Account With VISA Debit Card

Tags: developer-program, apple-store

Can anyone confirm whether Apple accepts VISA debit card to buy iOS Developer account that costs $99.

I can use the same card to purchase apps from the App Store but is this card can also be used to buy iOS developer account?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Apple iOS Developer](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/purchase-and-next-steps.html) website, only valid credit cards are accepted. Googling suggest attempted purchase using debit card didn't work, unfortunately.

It’s up to your bank to code whether the card is valid for Apple to charge in the region it decides to charge you for this product. Globally, many (if not most) debit cards will work for any Apple transaction, but some will not if your bank establishes a limit for transactions in the regional online store Apple uses for your transaction or otherwise restricts your card to local or country-specific ATM only. There are debit cards with very strict terms that will not work with Apple.

Answer (score 3):

I've used debit cards for years. But I'm in Europe, where debit cards are standard; it's possible that things are different in the US.

Comment: Good point. @AJ112, are you in Europe, US, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

I have just used VISA Debit card which works for me :)

Form says credit card details and however debit card works.

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, Your debit card is of which bank?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works. I have VISA Debit card issues by ICICI Bank in India. I bought the Apple Developer Program enrolment with that card and it was successful. I do not know about other banks. But in India and with ICICI it certainly works.

Comment: Is it international debit card or domestic debit card?

Comment: how do you check that?

Comment: How long did it take? I paid with Debit Card in India 3 days back and the payment has not been confirmed by Apple. But in the website it says it would take 2 days to process.

Answer (score -2):

Debit cards with "Verified by Visa" or "3D SecureCode" will failed on international transactions.

Please use any debit cards without these verification steps in order to bypass the USSD command to send you the verification code to your phone.

Comment: Just don't tell this to all the online stores I frequently buy stuff at with such a card :-)